# Sigma simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone please help to simplify 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{50}k(k-1)\binom{50}{k}\text{?}$$

The answer should be $50\cdot 49\cdot 2^{48}$.

Comment: Take the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{50}$. Take a second derivative. Set $x=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the binomial exapnsion of $(1+x)^{50}$ we get $\displaystyle (1+x)^{50}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}x^k$, so by differentiating both parts of the equation with respect to x, we get $\displaystyle 50 (1+x)^{49}=\sum_{k=1}^{50}k\binom{50}{k}x^{k-1}$. By 
differentiating again both parts of the last equation with respect to x, we get $\displaystyle 50\cdot 49\cdot  (1+x)^{48}=\sum_{k=2}^{50}k(k-1)\binom{50}{k}x^{k-2}$ and set $x=1$ to get the desired result $50\cdot 49\cdot 2^{48}$ for your expression.